# How to retrieve data using the rentrez package by giving a list of query names instead of a single one?

Tags: r, rentrez

So I'm trying to use the `rentrez` package to retrieve DNA sequence data from GenBank, giving as input a list of species.
What I've done is create a vector for the species I want to query, followed by creating a `term` where I specify the types of sequence data I want to retrieve, then creating a `search` that retrieves all the occurrences that match my query, and finally I create `data` where I retrieve the actual sequence data in fasta file.

```
library(rentrez)

species<-c("Ablennes hians","Centrophryne spinulosa","Doratonotus megalepis","Entomacrodus cadenati","Katsuwonus pelamis","Lutjanus fulgens","Pagellus erythrinus")

for (x in species){
term<-paste(x,"[Organism] AND (((COI[Gene] OR CO1[Gene] OR COXI[Gene] OR COX1[Gene]) AND (500[SLEN]:3000[SLEN])) OR complete genome[All Fields] OR mitochondrial genome[All Fields])",sep='',collapse = NULL)
search<-entrez_search(db="nuccore",term=term,retmax=99999)
data<-entrez_fetch(db="nuccore",id=search$ids,rettype="fasta")
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is concatenate the results of the queries for each species into a single variable. I began using a for cycle but I see it makes no sense in  this form because the data of each new species that is being queried is just replacing the previous one in `data`.

For some elements of `species`, there will be no data to retrieve and R shows this error:

```
Error: Vector of IDs to send to NCBI is empty, perhaps entrez_search or entrez_link found no hits?
```

In the cases where this error is shown and therefore there is no data for that particular species, I wanted the code to just keep going and ignore that.

My output would be a variable `data` which would include the sequence data retrived, from all the names in `species`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(rentrez)

species<-c("Ablennes hians","Centrophryne spinulosa","Doratonotus megalepis","Entomacrodus cadenati","Katsuwonus pelamis","Lutjanus fulgens","Pagellus erythrinus")

data <- list()

for (x in species){
  term<-paste(x,"[Organism] AND (((COI[Gene] OR CO1[Gene] OR COXI[Gene] OR COX1[Gene]) AND (500[SLEN]:3000[SLEN])) OR complete genome[All Fields] OR mitochondrial genome[All Fields])",sep='',collapse = NULL)
  search<-entrez_search(db="nuccore",term=term,retmax=99999)
  data[x] <- tryCatch({entrez_fetch(db="nuccore",id=search$ids,rettype="fasta")},
                      error = function(e){NA})
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. the thing is that, if a member of species the error I mentioned (Error: Vector of IDs to send to NCBI is empty...), then the for cycle stops and I don't get the subsequent data from the remaining species. is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Added an error handling function: tryCatch()